# Shader School answers, branching lesson (box)

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm finding it a bit tricky to reach the 'right' answers on shader school to learn GLSL.

One of them is lesson 4 - branching as the title, box as the GLSL filename. It mentions using lessthan()and similar component-wise comparison operations for vectors but without any working examples. I'm not finding any just using google either, so if anyone has working examples I'd appreciate it.

The task is to check a vec2 point p is within 2 vec2 high and low points. This is what I have so far:

```
bool inBox(highp vec2 lo, highp vec2 hi, highp vec2 p) {

  //Test if the point p is inside the box bounded by [lo, hi]
  return all(bvec2 (lessthan(p, hi), greaterthan(p, lo)));
}

#pragma glslify: export(inBox)
```

But the only solution that seems to work is:

```
bool inBox(highp vec2 lo, highp vec2 hi, highp vec2 p) {

  //Test if the point p is inside the box bounded by [lo, hi]
  return all(bvec2( all(lessThan(p, hi)), all(greaterThan(p, lo)) ));
}

#pragma glslify: export(inBox)
```

And I don't understand why, since I don't see why `lessthan()` or `greaterThan()` need to be wrapped in additional `all()`

Comment: `lessThan()` and `greaterThan()` appear to return a vector, not a scalar. `all()` returns a scalar indicating that "all" components of the vector operand are nonzero. So, you need a way to convert the vector results of `lessThan` and `greaterThan` into a single scalar `bool`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you include links to whatever course/problem you're referencing

Comment: This might come in handy for future reference: https://www.shaderific.com/glsl-functions